# Open the temporary file before it is saved in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Once you've uploaded a file, is it possible to open that file before the model is saved?

I'm using Paperclip to save files in the /public folder.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :open_it
  has_attached_file :upload

  def open_it
    a_file = open(upload.url) # this doesn't work before save ?
    # ... 
  end
end
```

Comment: Carrierwave can, believe paperclip can too..

Comment: @MikDiet I actually ended up using CarrierWave, am having a better experience with it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

found it:

```
def model_method
  f = open(self.upload.queued_for_write[:original].url)
end
```

Update:

Based on response from ecoologic, use `.path` instead of `.url` for more recent versions of the Paperclip gem

Comment: Hot dog!  Saved me some time.  I was using the after_post_process callback in my model and I was getting NO FILE FOUND when trying to read the file in the callback.

Answer (score 9):

Close enough, but `.url` didn't work for me, `path` worked.

```
file = open(uploaded.queued_for_write[:original].path)
```

did the trick.

P.S.: Don't forget to [close it](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/ensure.html) in an `ensure` block.